# How to use subprocess Popen?

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess, popen, raster

I'm trying to execute a command using Popen.

The command uses some PostGIS/Postgresql utility programs to upload a raster file to a database and works when executed from the command line. It uses unix style pipes to chain 2 commands and looks like this:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe" -d -I -C -e -Y -F -t 128x128 "C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif" test | "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -d adr_hazard -U postgres
```

When using within Python, I make it a string with the `'` codes:

```
command = '"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe" -d -I -C -e -Y -F -t 128x128 "C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif" test | "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -d adr_hazard -U postgres'
```

attempting to execute it results in an error:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command)

ERROR: Unable to read raster file: test
```

The error seems like the command was not parsed correctly (it is interpreting the wrong argument as the raster file)

Am I using `Popen` wrong?

Comment: try `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe", '-d', '-I', '-C', '-e', '-Y', '-F', '-t', '128x128', "C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif", 'test''])` if its working then take output in `PIPE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `command` uses pipe `|`. It requires a shell:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

The `command` itself as far as I can tell looks ok.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `shell=True` to achieve this effect. Given the [danger of insecure input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), it might be better to use the `stdout` and `stdin` keyword arguments instead.

Comment: @Arthur: Avoid cargo cult programming. There are no security issues here unless `command` is constructed using user input (it is a hardcoded string literal in the question). Without `shell=True` the call with the pipeline `a | b` would fail on non-Windows systems (I don't know about Windows).

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use `shell=True` to achieve this with pipes. This can be done programmatically with pipes even [where concern about insecure input is an issue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module). Here, `conn_params` is a dictionary with `PASSWORD`, `NAME` (database name), `USER`, and `HOST` keys.

```
raster2pgsql_ps = subprocess.Popen([
    'raster2pgsql', '-d', '-I', '-C', '-e', '-Y', '-F', '-t', '128x128',
    'C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif',
    'test'
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Connection made using conninfo parameters
# http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-connect.html
psql_ps = subprocess.check_output([
    'psql',
    'password={PASSWORD} dbname={NAME} user={USER} host={HOST}'.format(**conn_params),
], stdin=raster2pgsql_ps.stdout)
```

Comment: Note: `raster2pgsql_ps.stdout` stays open in the parent. On POSIX systems it suppresses SIGPIPE signal on write that may notify `raster2pgsql_ps` that `psql_ps` exited prematurely (closed the pipe (its stdin)). Here's [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22385908/4279). I don't know whether it has any effect on Windows. If you choose to write Windows-specific commands then there is no point to use a list argument if you already have the full command as a string (the list is converted to string in the `subprocess` module using `list2cmdline()` function on Windows).

Comment: That's true; I cannot try this approach on Windows, but I know it works on UNIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Windows, while avoiding `shell=True`

One can make use of Python's [fstring formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to make sure the commands will work in windows.

Please note that I used `shp2pgsql` but it should be a very similar process for `raster2pgsql`.

Parameters for the `shp2pgsql`: `srid` is the coordinate system of the shape file, `filename` is the path to the shape file to be imported, `tablename` is the name you'd like to give your table.

```
import os
import subprocess

shp2pgsql_binary = os.path.join(pgsql_dir, "bin", "shp2pgsql")
psql_binary = os.path.join(pgsql_dir, "bin", "psql")

command0 = f'\"{shp2pgsql_binary}\" -s {srid} \"{filename}\" {tablename}'
command1 = f'\"{psql_binary}\" \"dbname={databasename} user={username} password={password} host={hostname}\"'

try:
    shp2pgsql_ps = subprocess.Popen(command0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    psql_ps = subprocess.check_output(command1, stdin=shp2pgsql_ps.stdout)
except:
    sys.stderr.write("An error occurred while importing data into the database, you might want to \
                        check the SQL command below:")
    sys.stderr.write(command)
    raise
```

To adpat to `raster2pgsql`, you just need to modify the string in `command0`, e.g. `-s {srid}` becomes `-d -I -C -e -Y -F -t 128x128`. The string for `command1` can remain the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
  PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
  pd = subprocess.Popen(['"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe", '-d', '-I', '-C', '-e', '-Y', '-F', '-t', '128x128', "C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif", 'test'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  stdout, stderr = pd.communicate()
```

Comment: There is no need to convert the command into a list. `subprocess` uses `CreateProcess()` internally that requires a string anyway. `command` from the question looks ok as is. [The error may be elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22119565/4279).

Answer (score -2):

It will be better to use subprocess.Popen in this way:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe"', '-d', '-I', '-C', '-e', '-Y', '-F', '-t', '128x128', '"C:\\temp\\SampleDTM\\SampleDTM.tif"', 'test', '|', '"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\psql.exe"', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', '5432', '-d', 'adr_hazard', '-U', 'postgres'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.pipe, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.wait()
result = proc.stdout.readlines()#if you want to process the result of your command
proc.kill()
```

B.T.W, it's good to format the path first, use:

```
path = os.path.normalpath("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\raster2pgsql.exe")
```

this will avoid some path problems for different OS platform.

The `shell = True` is important if you want to execute your command just like executing it in local shell.

Hope will help you.

Comment: -1: there are *two* commands connected by the pipe (`|`). You are trying to start `raster2pgsql` with the rest of the pipeline as its arguments.

Comment: That is OK when you use the way as I said, the popen will generate all the command that with '' as an single command and pass it to the shell, in other word, the function will work. You need to try a command before you comment!!!

Comment: It might work on Windows because `subprocess` calls `list2cmdline()` unconditionally if it receives a list argument to convert it to a string. In the end it works as though you passed `'cmd1 | cmd2'` shell command as a single string. Passing it as `['cmd1', '|', 'cmd2']` is misleading (it implies that `|` and `cmd2` are arguments of `cmd1` or the shell) and this approach breaks on other platforms.

Comment: The function do works in windows platform, for linux, I checked, only some special command will "|" as an option may have some problem. But this question is under windows platform.

Comment: I understand that. I said *"might"* because your code has `stdout=PIPE` (in the wrong case) but it reads the output after `p.wait()` that may cause a deadlock  if the child process generates enough output.

Comment: I have said if you the user want to process the printout, otherwise, subprocess.call is much better if you just want to start a process. I commented my answer.

Comment: the point is: 1. your code doesn't work as is. Try it. 2. `.wait()` and `.readlines()` calls are in the wrong order 3. If the previous two issues are fixed then the command should work on Windows but it is a bad practice to pass `a | b` shell command as `['a', '|', 'b']`.