# Convert mp3 to wav on the fly using ffmpeg in Python

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to convert a mp3 file on the fly in Python to wav file using ffmpeg.

I call it using subprocess, how can I get it's output to play it as wav on the fly wthout saving it as the file (or playing it while its converting) and then playing it?

This is what I have so far:

I'm using aplay just for a example.

```
FileLocation = "/home/file.mp3"

subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-i", FileLocation etc etc "newfail.wav"])
os.system("aplay ... ") #play it on the fly here
```

As far as I understand, if I put "-" as file name, it will output it instead to stdout, but I don't know how to read stdout...

Comment: Why don't you play mp3 file directly? Do you want both play the file and save it to disk? Do you have an audio player that accepts input on  stdin?

Comment: I want to send it to another audioplayer directly (also using subprocess) and it supports only wav files, I just find it more convenient to do it on the fly instead of converting everything and then play wav file(s). The player I send the avi file does support input on stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate `source arg1 arg2 | sink` shell command without the shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

source = Popen(['source', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=PIPE)
sink = Popen(['sink'], stdin=source.stdout)
source.stdout.close()
source.wait()
sink.wait()
```